# Installing Hybrid in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hybrid

Hi I have try to install hybrid in my ubuntu pc but when I install it I unzip the file , but when I run ./Hybrid it give me :

```
./Hybrid: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

any help

my system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file is provided by the `libqt5multimedia5` package.

1. [Enable the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)
2. `sudo apt install libqt5multimedia5`
3. Then try your install again.